# Unable to retrieve the pricing configuration data for this region at this moment. Please retry

Tags: azure-sql-database

Azure:
Created SQL Azure Server
Created 2 Databases on the server
Now trying to create SQL Elastic pool for server
Tried Server to Create on 
East US
West US
Central US

When Compute+Storage:
I get below message:
Unable to retrieve the pricing configuration data for this region at this moment. Please retry.

My Resource Group is: Learn-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx

Why it does not allow to configure elastic pool?

Comment: Did the error solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is under maintenance now in your this region. I just tried and everything is ok. Please refresh portal , try again after a moment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were right, i tried after couple days, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VirulPatel, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you can't accept my answer, please  mark your answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried after couple days again, and it is working now
I was able to create elastic pool with eastus region.

Thanks,
V